# Assign value to Excel cells based on their colors

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a Project Management template in which I would like to have a visual overview of the status of different activities as follows:

STATUSES:

- Blue = Completed
- Green = In Progress
- Yellow = Delayed
- Red = Issue
- White/No color = Not Started

In each cell there will be the name of the responsible and the cell will be colored based on the status.

There are 4 columns of which I would like to calculate for each row the average (let's assume Blue is 100%, Green 50%. Yellow 30%, Red 20% and White 0%).

Can you please help me?

Thanks!

I tried with this link but it did not work

https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-formula-based-on-cell-color/#2_Excel_COUNTIF_and_SUMIF_Formula_by_Cell_Color

Comment: Use conditional formatting to apply the color based on the numbers, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the calculation (percentages) in **D** column, then you can use this number to generate the conditional formatting and also the label in column **E**. Since you don't have too many options, it would be enough to use `SWITCH` function. For example:

```
=SWITCH(D1:D5, 1, "Completed", 0.5, "In Progress", 0.3, "Delayed", 0.2, "issue", 
 0, "Not Started")
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]